# How to get the paragraph Number from Word Document in VSTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, vsto

Suppose we have a paragraph in a document as below:

1. Orange
2. Apple
3. Mango

I need to retrieve the Numbered List for each entities in the paragraph. For Orange- 1, Apple-2 and Mango-3
I have already used the below code to find out the list of Paragraphs in the document.
Word.Paragraphs para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs;

From para  object I need to find out the Numbering of the list for each entities.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% I understand your question but it appears you are using a numbered list style on the 3 paragraphs and you would like to get the values of the numbered list style? (1, 2 and 3)

A word Paragraph has in VBA/VSTO/etc.. a Range object
On the Range object you will find the ListFormat object which gives you the info you need.

So if you have in your first paragraph:
1. Orange
then you can use:

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.ListFormat.ListString
```

This will give you the "1." 
And

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.ListFormat.ListValue
```

This will give you the 1

Good luck